# punctuating speech - comma versus period

Tags: commas, speech, vocatives

If I said, "I will go fishing John will I go shopping today." If I take "Will I go shopping today" to be a separate sentence on its own. Is there a way of punctuating it so that the first part "I will go fishing" is NOT being addressed to John? Or is this not possible and by default the first part "I will go fishing" must be addressed to John and therefore the vocative comma must be used, "I will go fishing, John. Will I go shopping today?"

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you are asking. Your example sentence isn't a sentence.

Comment: If you don't want to address John then remove his name from the sentence. If this is some sort of punctuation exercise where you have to keep all of the words in that order then *John* would have to be associated with either or both of the fishing and shopping parts. In any case it sounds strange to ask "will *I* go shopping?"

Comment: Thank you. I have to keep those words in that order with the condition that "Will I got shopping today?" is a separate sentence. With these 2 rules, is it true that by default the vocative comma must be used and the only way of punctuating this sentence is "I Will go fishing, John. Will I go shopping today?" This was not my intent, my intent was to say to myself or to the group of people out loud, " I will go fishing" then say "John" to get his attention or to invoke him so that he pays attention to what I say afterwards, which was "Will I go shopping today?"

Comment: "I will go fishing. John, will I go shopping today?" You could use a dash, or even an exclamation mark, after John's name to indicate that the speaker has called it out to attract his attention.

Comment: Ah thank you. If I did not pause between fishing and John (because the thought of John suddenly came into my mind), instead of a period can I use a dash to make: I will go fishing-John! Will I go shopping today?